# jQuery - Multiple Check Boxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have looked for hours on the web with no luck!

I have 40 Check boxes, one check box must be checked at all times. Here's the twist, that one check box must be any one of the 40.

I know how to target just one single button...this is not the goal. The user must be able to choose which one is to remain active.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#W_E-helpPage01').click(function() {
         return false;
```

As for form validation that's not the ticket either. As this needs to be dynamic, it must prevent the user from deselecting all but one check box.

Example:
If 30 where to be check, and the user decided to uncheck all 30 he can not do this. As the rule is there must always be at-less one check, it doesn't matter which one but it must be random.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ricky

Comment: When your page loads, is one checkbox selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will stop the user from unchecking the last checked checkbox:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {    
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
});​
```

It checks to see if this click results in there being no checked check boxes and cancels the click if that is true.

http://jsfiddle.net/BQCK3/

Comment: Fantastic.......works beautifully - Thank you very much Richard. I don't know what I would do without this sight as I'm learning jQuery

Comment: an improvement is to cache a reference `cb = $('input:checkbox')` for using it on event binding and inside the function check for `if (cb.filter(':checked').length === 0)` : see http://jsfiddle.net/y6Qmq/

Comment: I don't know what I would do without this sight. Its great to know there are people such as you helping others to learn jQuery.

Comment: I will have to give that one a try also Fabrizio. Again thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a little fiddle that could solve this problem: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/akQvN/)

Html:

```
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" checked /><span>1</span><br />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" /><span>2</span><br />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" /><span>3</span><br />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" /><span>4</span><br />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" /><span>5</span><br />
<input class="cb" type="checkbox" /><span>6</span><br />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".cb").click(function(){

        if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
            if($(".cb:checked").length >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use the following example

 <input  class="Active test" type="checkbox" checked /><span>1</span><br />
 <input  class="InActive test" test" type="checkbox" /><span>2</span><br />
 <input  class="InActive test" test" type="checkbox" /><span>3</span><br />
 <input  class="InActive test" test" type="checkbox" /><span>4</span><br />
 <input  class="InActive test" test" type="checkbox" /><span>5</span><br />
 <input class="InActive test" type="checkbox" /><span>6</span><br />

 $('.test').live('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("Active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("Active");
        $(this).addClass("InActive");
    }
    else
        if ($(this).hasClass("InActive")) {
            $(this).removeClass("InActive");
            $(this).addClass("Active");
        }
    // alert($('.Active').length);
    if ($('.Active').length == 0) {
        alert("Atleast one checkbox is required")
        $(this).addClass("Active");
        return false;
    }
});
```